# `dpkg -l`コマンドの出力結果に表示される"iU"の意味を教えてください

Tags: ubuntu

## 環境

- XUbuntu 18.04

## 質問

`dpkg -l`コマンドでパッケージの一覧を確認しています。
先頭の`iU`はどのような意味でしょうか？

```
$ dpkg -l |grep python3.9
ii  libpython3.9-minimal:amd64             3.9.12-1+bionic1                          amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.9)
ii  libpython3.9-stdlib:amd64              3.9.12-1+bionic1                          amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.9)
iU  python3.9                              3.9.13-1+bionic1                          amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.9)
iU  python3.9-minimal                      3.9.13-1+bionic1                          amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.9)
```

`dpkg -l`の先頭行から、`iU`は"インストール/展開"を意味するのは分かりましたが、"展開"の具体的な意味が分かりませんでした。

```
$ dpkg -l | head -n 3
要望=(U)不明/(I)インストール/(R)削除/(P)完全削除/(H)保持
| 状態=(N)無/(I)インストール済/(C)設定/(U)展開/(F)設定失敗/(H)半インストール/(W)トリガ待ち/(T)トリガ保留
|/ エラー?=(空欄)無/(R)要再インストール (状態,エラーの大文字=異常)
```

公式のページなどがあれば、そのリンクも教えていただきたいです。

## 追加質問

- 展開の"U"は"Uncompress"の"U"なのでしょうか？

Comment: "U" は "Unpacked" の "U" です。`man dpkg-query` の `-l` オプションの説明部分に記載されています。"unpacked" の意味は `man dpkg` の "INFORMATION ABOUT PACKAGES" の項にあります。"The package is unpacked, but not configured."

Comment: ありがとうございます。マニュアルに書いてありましたね。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

オンライン man-pagesでは

- Ubuntu Manpage [dpkg](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)
- Debian Manpages [dpkg - Debian パッケージマネージャ](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg/dpkg.1.ja.html)

(Ubuntuは, 元は Debianから派生し, 一般的な情報は Ubuntuのほうが豊富だが, この手の情報は Debianのほうが多いこともあるので)

```bash
$ LANG=C dpkg -l python3
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version         Architecture Description
+++-==============-===============-============-=========================================================================
ii  python3        3.10.4-0ubuntu2 amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
```

iU ならば以下の通りで, インストールを要望し, パッケージは展開されたが まだ設定されていない。… という状態

> Desired=Install
> Status=Unpacked